# setup Cronjob to call php framework's method in cpanel

Tags: php, yii, cron, cpanel

I have written a code to call the mailing functionality, which will run on a particular time. I am using Yii framework and I want to call a someMethod of someController.

I have written `wget http://example.com/mycontroller/mymethod` in the command field, it is running, but sends mail only to the first email of the database. After that, it throws an error of 404 not found:

```
Connecting to example.com|50.22.11.25|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-08-25 01:15:08 ERROR 404: Not Found.`
```

What is the correct syntax of the cronjob command?

Here is the code which I am trying to run via cronJob:

```
<?php
    class SendMailController extends Controller
    {
        public function actionSendMailUsingCronJob()
        {
            $response = array();
            $countMail = 0;
            $mail_template = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('mail_mailing_template')
            ->where('status=:status', array(':status'=>'not_sent'))
            ->queryAll();
            foreach ($mail_template as $single){
                $html = $single['template'];
                $subject = $single['subject'];
                if($single['send_to'] == 'student'){
                    $response['tbl_used'] = 'students';
                    $mailingList =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                                ->select('*')
                                ->from('mail_students')
                                ->queryAll();
                }
                elseif($single['send_to'] == 'owtrainer'){
                    $response['tbl_used'] = 'gym_owner';
                    $mailingList =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('mail_gym_owners')
                    ->queryAll();
                }
                elseif($single['send_to'] == 'all'){
                    $response['tbl_used'] = 'all';
                    $student_list =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('mail_students')
                    ->queryAll();
                    $ownerTrainer_list =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('mail_gym_owners')
                    ->queryAll(); 
                    $mailingList = array_merge($student_list,$ownerTrainer_list);
                    
                }
                foreach ($mailingList as $singleMail){
                        $this->sendMailToUsers($response,$singleMail,$subject,$html);
                }
            }
        }
        public function sendMailToUsers($response,$user,$subject,$html){
            require_once('helper/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
            $from_email=Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
            $webName=Yii::app()->name;
        
        
            $mail    = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->Subject = $subject ;
                
        
            $total_count = 0;
                
            $mail->AddAddress($user['users_email']) ;
                    
            $mail->SetFrom($from_email, $webName);
            $mail->AddReplyTo($from_email,$webName);
                
        
            $body = "".$html."";
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            try{
                $sent = $mail->Send();
                if($sent) {
                    if($response['tbl_used'] == 'students'){
                        $model = Students::model()->findByPk($user['user_id']);
                    }elseif($response['tbl_used'] == 'gym_owner'){
                        $model = GymTrainersOwners::model()->findByPk($user['user_id']);
                    }elseif($response['tbl_used'] == 'all'){
                        return true;
                    }
                    if($model){
                        $model->count_sent =$model->count_sent +1;
                        $model->update();
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
            }
                
        
        }
    }
```

Here is the cronjob command I am using:

```
wget http://www.example.com/controller/method
```

Comment: Please provide your current code and the command you are using in the cronjobs list.

Comment: So your controller is in a module filtraqmail or filtraqmail is your Yii webroot? Do I understand correctly that your script sends 1 mail and crashes after that? Can you output the Exception message being thrown at the end?

Comment: filtraqmail is my webroot

Comment: I have resolved this problem by using
`curl http://www.example.com/controller/method`
Now all users are able to receive the mail correctly it is not throwing any error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a cron to call yii, the best way of doing that is using a command actually.

Comment: you can create a command under protected/commands (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html for yii2 and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/es/topics.console for yii1.x) and then just call "php yiic <<yourcommand>>" like you call the migration command or translation command for example.

Comment: If i don't have access to the command since i am using the shared hosting.. then how can should i approach?

Comment: if you can set up a cronjob then, you could call a yii command as that job ("php <path/to/app> yiic <your command>")